# UIWebView inside a UICollectionViewCell won't scroll, is disabled

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, uicollectionview, touchesbegan

So I have a custom UICollectionViewCell with a UIWebview inside and when I load up my collection view the html loads inside the web view just fine but I am not able to interact with it (scroll, zoom, etc).  Its as if the web view has userinteraction disabled (but thats clearly not so).  Ive searched for a while now and can't seem to find a solution to this...

Heres the snippet of code I'm using to load this particular cell :

```
cell = (WWPlayerResultsCell *) [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"statsDetailResults" forIndexPath:indexPath];


if (cell == nil) {
    NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"WWPlayerResultsCell" owner:nil options:nil];
    cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
}

[((WWPlayerResultsCell*) cell) setUrlStr:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://google.com"]];
[((WWPlayerResultsCell*) cell) loadWebView];

return cell;
```

[image: UICollectionView Screen]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution...apparently the top view (view at [nib objectAtIndex:0];) was set to UIView instead of a UICollectionViewCell.  Made this change in IB and all was well..silly mistake.